# Interface overload?

Tags: c#, oop

So i think i maybe over-complicating things in my implementation, but here's what i'm doing:

1. I want my database represented by IRepository
2. SQLRepository is a concrete implementation of IRepository.
3. I want all Tables in the Database represented by ITable.
4. I have a table called Items, which is represented by ItemsTable.
5. Each record in Items Table is represented by IItem.
6. Item is a concrete implementation of IItem.

Now my problem is, in my program when i want to use List items = repository.Items.List(); it won't compile because in ItemsTable the implementation of ITable return IList and not List. I could return IList but i do want to work with a concrete List of Items.

What can i do better?

```
 public interface ITable
    {
        IList<IItem> List();
        bool Add(IItem item);
        bool Delete(long itemId);
        bool Find(long itemId);
    }

public class ItemsTable : ITable
{
    public IList<IItem> List()
    {
        IList<IItem> items = GetItems(); // GetItems return List<Item>, Item implements IItem.
        return items;
    }

   .....
   ...
   ..
}

public class SQLRepository : IRepository
{
    ITable items = new ItemsTable();

    public ITable Items
    {
        get { return items; }
    }
}


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var repository = new SQLRepository();
        List<Item> items = repository.Items.List();
    }
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged both c# and Java?

Comment: Do you have any problem with working IList<T> as of now?

Comment: I think it's more of a design question not really a c# specific question, if i was coding in java i would end up with the same question.

Comment: @zenwalker  Yes i don't want to work of IList<T>, i want to work of List<Item> because Item exposes additional methods that IItem does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be changing your interface to:

```
public interface ITable<TItem>
    where TItem : IItem
{
    IList<TItem> List();
    bool Add(TItem item);
    bool Delete(long itemId);
    bool Find(long itemId);
}
```

Comment: I plan to have additional implementations of IItem apart from Item

Comment: I did't use anywhere in my answer name `Item`. So you can use there anything that implements `IItem` interface.

Comment: Doesn't this answer somewhat defeat the entire purpose of using interfaces to abstract away the underlying concrete classes?

Comment: No, because with interface you can use properties and methods defined with interface. Without it items would be treated as `objects`

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of comments for you.

First up, just because you're defining interfaces that map to **your** concrete classes you don't need to **use** interfaces everywhere. The point of using interfaces list you are using is to limit the surface area that users of your repository and objects get to play with. So feel free to return `List<T>` rather than `IList<T>`.

Secondly & however, returning anything that implements `IList<T>` implies that you want to modify the contents of the list after you get it from your repository. Now doing that can be bad and bad for a number of reasons.

If your repository keeps references to the lists it returns then subsequent callers can get your modified lists - so you really can't keep references. So you need to build the lists for every call.

If you build the list for every call then you are effectively calling a `.ToList` operator prior to returning your results.

The alternative is to allow the caller to decide when they call `.ToList` and then you can just return an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Now this is better in many ways.

It lets calling code know that the list hasn't been modified be another caller. And it also allows the list to requery itself for every new iteration of the list.

So, my recommendation is - don't return `IList<T>` or `List<T>` - return `IEnumerable<T>` instead and let the caller call `.ToList()`.

Comment: I agree with using IEnumerable. That's what I ended up doing, but the question was regarding the compiler error so that's why I accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my problem is, in my program when i want to use List items = repository.Items.List(); it won't compile because in ItemsTable the implementation of ITable return IList and not List. I could return IList but i do want to work with a concrete List of Items.

Well. You can't have both. If you want to work with a `List<T>` you need to return one. You can't create a contract that says that any `IList<T>` implementation is OK and then expect a `List<T>` to be returned.

Those kind of violations usually render a maintance mess in the future since `IList<IItem> List();` promise one thing and you expect it to deliver something else. It's like going to the gas station and order unleaded gas and expect leaded gas (it's still gas, but with a bit of led).

Answer (score 0):

There is no variance in .NET for generic collections.

Implement the interface method explicitly, and provide an overload that returns a concrete list:

```
public MyTable : ITable
{
   IList<IItem>ITable List()
   {
      return List().OfType<IItem>().ToList();
   }


   public List<MyItem> List()
   {

      var l = new List<MyItem>();

      ...

      return l;
   }
}
```